# How to get a Swing ListSelectionEvent's "source" item?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listselectionlistener

I am trying to write a `ListSelectionListener` for a `JList` that knows which list item the user is selecting away from, and which list item the user is selecting to. So if a list has three items in it `{Apple, Orange, Pear}`, and the current selection is on `Orange` and the user selects `Pear`, then:

- `srcFruit` is `Orange`; and
- `destFruit` is `Pear`

Here's the code I have:

```
myList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent fruitSelectionEvent) {
        printSourceAndDestFruit(myList, fruitSelectionEvent);
    }
});

private void printSourceAndDestFruit(JList list, ListSelectionEvent event) {
    FruitVO srcFruit = (FruitVO)list.getModel().getElementAt(event.getFirstIndex());
    FruitVO destFruit = (FruitVO)list.getModel().getElementAt(event.getLastIndex());

    System.out.println("srcFruit = " + srcFruit.getName() + " and destFruit = " = destFruit.getName());
}
```

When the application loads and initializes the `JList`, there is no default selection. When I take the following actions:

1. Click `Orange`
2. Click `Pear`
3. Click `Orange` again

Here's the print out I get:

```
srcFruit = Orange and destFruit = Pear
srcFruit = Orange and destFruit = Pear
```

Where am I going wrong here? Are `getFirstIndex()`/`getLastIndex()` buggy or just not the correct Swing methods to be using?

Here's the output I should be seeing:

```
srcFruit = Orange and destFruit = Pear
srcFruit = Pear and destFruit = Orange
```

So even though I made 3 selects (mouse clicks), since the first time I click `Orange` wasn't a change from one value to the next, I *believe* it is correct to not fire and call `printSourceAndDestFruit`. The I select `Pear` and it is correct in stating that `srcFruit` is `Orange` and that `destFruit` is `Pear`. But when I click back to `Orange` the 2nd println should have `srcFruit` as `Pear` and `destFruit` as `Orange`. **Why doesn't it?!?!**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first and last index are not what you think they are. Here's what the javadoc says:

> getFirstIndex()
>
> Returns the index of the first row whose selection may have changed.
>
> getLastIndex()
>
> Returns the index of the last row whose selection may have changed.

So, since the selection of pear and orange changes at each click, and since pear is after orange in the list, `getFirstIndex()` always returns Orange and `getLastIndex()` always returns Pear.

If you want to compare the new selection with the last one, then keep the last selection in some member variable, and compare it with the new selection each time the selection changes, and `getValueIsAdjusting()` returns false.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that selection is in the order `Orange`, `Pear` is that the `DefaultListSelectionModel` calls [fireValueChanged](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListSelectionModel.html#fireValueChanged%28int,%20int%29) solely based on the items index location in the `ListModel` rather than the new selection index.

This related [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6378891) asked a similar question but shows that this was normal behavior and showed that you could add a workaround by using:

```
FruitVO srcFruit = (FruitVO)list.getModel().getElementAt(list.getMinSelectionIndex());
FruitVO destFruit = (FruitVO)list.getModel().getElementAt(list.getMaxSelectionIndex());
```